# What is the difference between resolved sideband cooling and electromagnetically induced transparancey (EIT) cooling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser, quantum-optics

Both [Resolved sideband cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolved_sideband_cooling) and [EIT cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_induced_transparency#EIT_cooling) seem to rely on exciting the 'red-sideband' transition
$$
|g,n> \quad \rightarrow \quad |e,n-1>
$$ with a laser, which then de-excites on the 'carrier' transition
$$
|e,n-1> \quad \rightarrow \quad |g,n-1>
$$
effectively cooling the particle by one quantum number within one cooling cycle. $g$, $e$ are the ground and excited state and $n$, $n-1$ are the motional quantum numbers.

Where is the difference exactly?

Comment: One significant difference is that resolved-sideband cooling is performed step-like, as a sequence of excitation-deexcitation pulses, whereas EIT cooling is a continuous process.

Comment: Also, EIT cooling scheme is essentially three-level, whereas sideband cooling utilizes two levels only.